# Example of infinite field of characteristic $p\neq 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, examples-counterexamples, positive-characteristic

Can you give me an example of infinite field of characteristic $p\neq0$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 234, accepted):

One very important example of an infinite field of characteristic $p$ is
$$\mathbb{F}_p(T)=\left\{\,\frac{f}{g}\,\Bigg|\,\,\,f,g\in\mathbb{F}_p[T], g\neq0\right\},$$

the [rational functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) in the indeterminate $T$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_p$ (the symbol $\mathbb{F}_p$ is just a synonym for $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$). In other words, these are ratios of polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_p[T]$; this is [the same construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions) as the one we use to make $\mathbb{Q}$ from $\mathbb{Z}$. The field $\mathbb{F}_p(T)$ is infinite because, for example, it contains $1$, $T$, $T^2$, $\ldots$, and it is of characteristic $p$ because it contains $\mathbb{F}_p$ (alternatively, because the kernel of the unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{F}_p(T)$ is $p\mathbb{Z}$.)

Another important example is $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$, the [algebraic closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure) of the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$. If you accept, for the moment, that every field has an algebraic closure (which is certainly not an obvious statement), then the fact that [there are no finite algebraically closed fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56397/do-finite-algebraically-closed-fields-exist/56398#56398) means that the algebraic closure of a field of characteristic $p$ will have to be an infinite field of characteristic $p$.

---

Michael Hardy raises some good questions below.

- *Is one of $\mathbb{F}_p(T)$, $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ a subfield of the other?*
- *Is $\mathbb{F}_p(T)$ algebraically closed?*
- *What is the relationship between these two fields?*

These questions are all related. First, we should look at the definitions of [algebraic element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_element), [algebraic extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_extension), [algebraically closed field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field), and [algebraic closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure).

- Given a field $K$, and another field $L$ containing $K$ (i.e., $L\supseteq K$), we say that $\alpha\in L$ is an **algebraic element over $K$** (or, for short, just that "$\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$") when there exists some (non-zero) $f\in K[x]$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$. If $\alpha\in L$ is *not* algebraic over $K$, we say it is **transcendental** over $K$. Wikipedia presents the following (standard) examples:
- $\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{R}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$, because there is a non-zero polynomial $f\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ (i.e., $f$ has rational coefficients) such that $f(\sqrt{2})=0$; we could take $f=x^2-2$, or $f=3x^3-6x$, or any other polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with $\sqrt{2}$ as a root.
- $\pi\in\mathbb{R}$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$, because there is no non-zero polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ with $\pi$ as a root; in other words, $\pi$ satisfies no algebraic relation with the rational numbers.
- However, $\pi$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{R}$, because there are many easy examples of non-zero polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ with $\pi$ as a root - first and foremost, $x-\pi$. (Given any field $K$, any $\alpha\in K$ is algebraic over $K$ because $x-\alpha$ is a polynomial in $K[x]$ having $\alpha$ as a root. This demonstrates the importance of specifying algebraic (or transcendental) *over what field*.)
- The setup of two fields $K$ and $L$, with $L\supseteq K$, is referred to as a *field extension.* We refer to the extension as a single entity by the expression $L/K$ (this is **not a quotient** like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group) or [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring), though). An extension $L/K$ is an **algebraic extension** when *every* $\alpha\in L$ is algebraic over $K$.
- A field $K$ is **algebraically closed** when any *non-constant* $f\in K[x]$ (i.e., $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\geq 1$) has a root in $K$.
  **The requirement that the root is in $K$ is the key property.**  For example, any non-constant polynomial $f\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ has a root, but some of them (e.g. $x^2+1$) don't have any roots that are actually in $\mathbb{R}$; thus $\mathbb{R}$ is not algebraically closed. (The fact that $\mathbb{C}$ *is* algebraically closed is often referred to as the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra)).
- Given any field $K$, there exists an algebraic extension $L/K$ such that $L$ is algebraically closed; such an $L$ is called an **algebraic closure of $K$**. It is unique up to isomorphism (so we often talk about "the" algebraic closure of $K$), and we write $L=\overline{K}$, or sometimes $L=K^{\text{alg}}$.

Now we have the concepts necessary to compare and contrast $\mathbb{F}_p(T)$ and $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$.

First, note that $T\in\mathbb{F}_p(T)$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{F}_p$ - there's no non-zero $f\in\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ such that $f(T)=0$. This is really what we originally meant when we said $T$ is an "[indeterminate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_(variable))" - it stands in no relation to $\mathbb{F}_p$, we have only added it in as a formal symbol, so the only way we can get
$$a_nT^n+\cdots+a_1T+a_0=0\text{ for }a_i\in\mathbb{F}_p$$
is if every $a_i=0$, so there is no non-zero polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_p$ having $T$ as a root. In fact, *any element of* $\mathbb{F}_p(T)$ *that isn't itself an element of* $\mathbb{F}_p$ (i.e., anything having a $T$ in it) is transcendental over $\mathbb{F}_p$, by the same argument - so the extension $\mathbb{F}_p(T)/\mathbb{F}_p$ is really super-duper non-algebraic.

However, *every* element of $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_p$, because part of the definition of algebraic closure includes that the extension $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}/\mathbb{F}_p$ is algebraic.

So, if we had $\mathbb{F}_p(T)\subseteq\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$, then we'd have transcendental elements inside our algebraic extension $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}/\mathbb{F}_p$, which is a contradiction.

On the other hand, if we had $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}\subseteq\mathbb{F}_p(T)$, then we would have that there were some $\frac{f}{g}\in \mathbb{F}_p(T)$ such that $\frac{f}{g}\notin\mathbb{F}_p$ and $\frac{f}{g}\in\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ (because $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ is infinite and $\mathbb{F}_p$ is finite), and they would have to be algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_p$, which we've also seen is a contradiction.

Thus, neither $\mathbb{F}_p(T)\subseteq\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ nor $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}\subseteq\mathbb{F}_p(T)$.

It is also easy to see that $\mathbb{F}_p(T)$ is not algebraically closed; for the sake of simplicity, let's set $K=\mathbb{F}_p(T)$. If $K$ were algebraically closed, then every non-constant $f\in K[x]$ would have to have a root in $K$; but there are many such $f$'s that do not, for example $f=x^2-T$ (remember, $T\in K$, so don't be thrown by the existence of two indeterminates; this is just like $x^2-2$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$). If the polynomial $x^2-T$ had a root $\frac{f}{g}\in K=\mathbb{F}_p(T)$, then
$$\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)^2-T=0$$
$$f^2=Tg^2$$
$$2\cdot\deg(f)=\deg(f^2)=\deg(Tg^2)=1+2\cdot\deg(g)$$
which is a contradiction (can't have even = odd). This mirrors the usual proof that there is no $\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2=2$, i.e. that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational; the $\deg$ function is analogous to the [2-adic order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order). (As  Pierre-Yves Gaillard points out in the comments, this actually shows that $K(T)$ is not algebraically closed, for *any* field $K$.)

So, in summary, what is the relationship between the fields $\mathbb{F}_p(T)$ and $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$? Other than the fact that they are both extensions of $\mathbb{F}_p$, not much. The extension $\mathbb{F}_p(T)/\mathbb{F}_p$ is not algebraic, while the extension $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}/\mathbb{F}_p$ is; in fact the only elements $\mathbb{F}_p(T)$ and $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$ have in common are $\mathbb{F}_p$ itself. They are both extremely important in algebra, number theory, algebraic geometry, and they both fundamental examples of characteristic $p$ fields.

Comment: What is the relationship between these two fields?  Is one a subfield of the other?  Is the first one algebraically closed?

Comment: @Michael: I got carried away answering your questions :)

Comment: @Zev: You can use `\quad` as a long space; and `\Bigg|` as a long pipe. No need for excessive TeX code :)

Comment: @Asaf: Thanks for the tips :) I'd forgotten about `\Bigg`, although the spacing was intentional; sometimes I want to fine tune the spacing and `\quad`'s and `\qquad`'s are too big (but after reconsidering, it looks fine with a single `\,` on each side, anyway).

Comment: Dear Zev: Your argument shows that K(T) is not algebraically closed for any field $K$, doesn't it? Wonderful answer! +1

Comment: @Pierre: Indeed it does! And thank you for your compliment!

Comment: @ZevChonoles: I wonder if there are more examples, this is the only example that I know of.

Comment: @ramanujan_dirac there are many more examples built out of these by taking algebraic closures, adding more indeterminates, etc. One also has a field of formal Laurent series, i.e. power series with finitely many terms of negative degree, $K((X_1...X_n))$ for any field $K$, which are of characteristic $p$ when $K$ is for the same reasons as above. More general than Laurent series are Puiseux series, with fractional exponents-though these coincide with $\overline{K((X))}$ when $K=\bar{K}$. I'd also mention ultraproducts; and Lowenheim-Skolem guarantees examples of arbitrary cardinality.

Answer (score 30):

Another construction, using a tool from the formal logic: the [ultraproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct).

The cartesian product of fields
$$P = {\Bbb F}_p\times{\Bbb F}_{p^2}\times{\Bbb F}_{p^3}\times\cdots$$
isn't a field ("isn't a model of..." ) because has zero divisors:
$$(0,1,0,1,\cdots)(1,0,1,0\cdots)=(0,0,0,0,\cdots).$$
The solution is taking a quotient: let $\mathcal U$ be a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\Bbb N$. Define
$$(a_1,a_2,\cdots)\sim(b_1,b_2,\cdots)$$
when
$$\{n\in\Bbb N\,\vert\, a_n=b_n\}\in\mathcal U.$$
The quotient $F=P/\sim$ will be a infinite field of characteristic $p$.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but won't $\mathbb{F}_p^\mathbb{N} / \mathcal{U}$ be isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_p$, because every element of  $\mathbb{F}_p^\mathbb{N}$ is constant on a set in $\mathcal{U}$?

Comment: @TrevorWilson, I see the problem (is obvious for $p=2$). I will think if the example is repairable.

Comment: @TrevorWilson, the solution is taking the product of all the $F_{p^n}$. I will edit the answer later.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Does “later” still include now? ;)

Comment: @Luke, the answer was edited a few days after the comment.

Comment: Oh, I misread. I thought the error was that you had to take only the $F_{p^{n!}}$. I should've read the comment more carefully. Thanks for your quick response.