# Infinite Field of Characteristic 5

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I recently took an exam in which the professor asked to give an example of an infinite field of characteristic 5.

I had studied this problem, and found examples such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58424/example-of-infinite-field-of-characteristic-p-neq-0).

My answer that I wrote down was $F=\displaystyle\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{5\mathbb{Z}}$. My professor said that was wrong because $F \simeq \mathbb{Z}_5$ which is a finite field. Is he correct? Do I have an argument? How can I prove him wrong?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ has five elements and only five elements (each element is a set which contains infinitely many integers, but *this* set has only five things in it), so it is not an infinite field. 
You cannot prove him wrong, because he is not wrong.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ only has $5$ elements, which, regrettably, is finite. Sorry mate.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that writing $\frac{\mathbb Z}{5\mathbb Z}$ is not exactly a good idea in terms of notation because this is not a fraction. The standard notation for quotients is the forward slash, thus $\mathbb Z / 5\mathbb Z$ is what you should use from now on to denote quotients.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/58424/18880

Comment: @Patrick, HUH? We write quotients **literally** all the time in that way. Here we have someone having problems with seeing the finiteness of a $Z/5$: introducing very strange notational complications is hardly helpful.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I am writing a comment, not an answer; you're welcome to disagree. I write fractions that way (as in elements of a field or some localized ring), but I avoid writing group or ring quotients (or any kind of algebraic structure quotient) like this at all costs. Even when doing the isomorphism theorems, I prefer $(R/\mathfrak a)/(\mathfrak b/\mathfrak a) \simeq (R/\mathfrak b)$ over $\frac{R/\mathfrak a}{\mathfrak b/\mathfrak a} \simeq \frac R{\mathfrak b}$ all the time, and I can't remember of a book who didn't agree with me. Happy to be proved wrong though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He is not at all wrong. By mere definition $F=\mathbb{Z}_5$, no? Even if the whole being-a-field/ring thing is screwing you up, you know that, if nothing else, $F$ is a quotient group and $|F|=[\mathbb{Z}:5\mathbb{Z}]=5$.

Comment: By definition $\mathbb Z_5$ is the cyclic group with $5$ elements. $\mathbb Z / 5\mathbb Z$ is just isomorphic to it =) it is impressive how most of us think of isomorphic things as "the same things". I am actually liking your answer.

Answer (score 3):

He is correct, and there is nothing to back up your case I'm afraid. It should be very clear to you that $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ is finite. If it isn't, I would respectfully suggest that you go back to review the basics of group theory.

A proper example would have been the field of rational functions with coefficients in $\mathbb{\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}}$.

Comment: This example is indeed correct. It requires understanding well the difference between polynomials and polynomial functions though. To my amazement I found that Lang, Linear Algebra, *defines* polynomials (over *any* field) as polynomial functions, and starts stating a patently false theorem that their coefficients can be recovered (which is conveniently only proved for the reals and the complexes).

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong, and the professor is correct. Consider the division algorithm: for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, there exist $q\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $0\leq r<5$ such that $n=5q+r$. Thus, for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have
$$n+5\mathbb{Z}=r+5\mathbb{Z}$$
for some $r\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. It is also easily checked that these are distinct; thus, $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ has exactly 5 elements. In particular, $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

Here we have Z/5Z is a set with some elements which are also set. In Z/5Z there are 5 distinct elements(sets). Sets which are belongs to Z/5Z are infinite set but total number of sets(elements) in Z/5Z are finite(5). Thus we conclude Z/5Z is finite set. Obviously Z/5Z is a field with characteristics 5 but this is finite.