# How to show that every element involving $x$ in $F_p(x)/F_p$ is not algebraic.

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

In the field extension $F_p(x)/F_p$, where $F_p(x)$ is the field of fractions of polynomials over $F_p$, is it by definition that $x \in F_p(x)$ is not algebraic? In other words, should I claim that $x$ is indeterminate when I make this field extension, otherwise somehow it is no longer the field of fractions. In other words, if  $x \in F_p$ perhaps $F_p(x)$ is a smaller field than the field of fractions.

Further, I read in an answer here: [Example of infinite field of characteristic $p\neq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58424/example-of-infinite-field-of-characteristic-p-neq-0) that any element in $F_p(x)$ that involves $x$ will not be algebraic over $F_p$, but I don't see how.

Comment: That $x$ is not algebraic is obvious: Evaluating a polynomial in $x$ at $x$ just gives you that polynomial back; it is only $0$ if it was $0$. The harder question is why other non-constant rational functions $a \in F_p\left(x\right)$ are not algebraic. To show that, write $a$ as $u/v$ for two coprime polynomials $u$ and $v$, and try to get a contradiction from assuming that $a$ is algebraic.

Comment: @darijgrinberg so in this case $x$ is assumed not to be an element of $F_p$, right? Otherwise evaluating a polynomial at $x$ would yield some element in $F_p$, and perhaps that element is zero. Am I missing the point of the word "indeterminate"? Is it supposed to mean 'placeholder' i.e. 'don't think of this as an element in any field'?

For the second part, Let $\frac{u}{v} \in F_p(t)$ be algebraic, then suppose $a_0+a_1\frac{u}{v} +a_2 (\frac{u}{v})^2 + ... + a_n (\frac{u}{v} )^n=0$. Playing around with this I haven't been able to get a contradiction (I assume it should come from 'coprime')

Comment: Nope, $x$ is an indeterminate -- the one from the polynomial ring $F_p\left[x\right]$.

Comment: And as for the contradiction, try multiplying by $v^n$ and checking which of the resulting addends are divisible by $u$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg

So $a_0 v^n + ... + a_nu^n=0$. Since $0$ is divisible by $u$, the left-hand side is divisible by $u$, hence every term on the sum is divisible by $u$, hence $v^n$ is divisible by $u$, therefore $v$ is divisible by $u$, contradiction.

How does this look?

Comment: Almost. "$v^n$ divisible by $u$" does not yield "$v$ divisible by $u$", but it still contradicts the assumption that $u$ and $v$ are coprime (okay, I forgot to say that you have to make that assumption).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Oh ok, that makes sense. Thanks!