# Counting Right and Left Inverses of a Matrix (Linear Transformation)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, solution-verification

Let $\mathbb F$ be a finite field and let $T: \mathbb F^n \rightarrow \mathbb F^m$ be a linear transformation.

Suppose $n < m$, and that  $T$ is injective (i.e. $T$ has a left inverse).

I am curious if I have counted the left inverses of $T$ correctly.

**Attempt**

It is clear that if $(e_1,...,e_n)$ is a basis of $\mathbb F^n$, then $(Te_1,...,Te_n)$ is a basis of Im $T$.

Extending this to a basis of $\mathbb F^m$ gives $(Te_1,...,Te_n, w_{n+1},...,w_m)$,

whence we can define $T^{-1}_L$ (the left inverse of $T$) by

$$T^{-1}_L (T(e_i)) = e_i$$
$$T^{-1}_L (w_j) = v_j$$

where $v_j \in \mathbb F^n$ is arbitrary.

This gives $(| \mathbb F |^n)^{m-n}$ choices for the left inverse of $T$.

$\square$

Next, suppose $n > m$, and that  $T$ is surjective (i.e. $T$ has a right inverse).

Again, I attempt to count the right inverses of $T$.

**Attempt**

By the dimension formula, dim Ker $T = n - m$.

Let $(w_1,...,w_m)$ be a basis for $\mathbb F^m$. Since $T$ is surjective, we can find $(v_1,...,v_m)$ s.t. $T(v_i) = w_i$.

We define $T^{-1}_R$ (the right inverse of $T$) by

$$T^{-1}_R (T(v_i)) = v_i + a_i$$

where $a_i \in $ Ker $T$ is arbitrary.

This gives $|$Ker $T|^m = (| \mathbb F |^{n-m})^m$ choices for the right inverse of $T$.

$\square$

**Background:** This is a followup to a [similar question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3576994/matrix-inversion-basic-facts-and-heuristics)