# Prove or disprove that if V is a finite set over F with a dimension 1, then F is a finite field.

Tags: linear-algebra

I think it is a True statement, and my proof is as follows:

let $\theta $ be the additive identity in F

Given any element v in V, since v + v = $\theta$ v + $\theta$ v = 2$\theta$ v, then 2$\theta$ $\in$ F, and $\frac{\theta}{2} \in$ F, hence $\frac{\theta}{2}v \in$ V, by this argument we can construct infinite $\{2v, \frac{\theta}{2}v , 3v,  \frac{\theta}{3}v...\}$

Hence V cannot be finite, and we are done.

Comment: What is the meaning of dimension of a finite set?

Comment: Maybe you could specify the conditions on $F$ as well. Is your claim this:
Let $F$ be a field and $V$ be $F$-vector space of dimension 1. Then, if $V$ is a finite set, then also $F$ is a finite set (in particular a finite field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic fact is that for a finite dimensional vector space $V $ over a field
$\mathbb F $ ,  we have $|V|=|\mathbb F|^{\rm {dim}V} $.

This forces $|\mathbb F|\le|V|$.

---

For if $\lambda\cdot v=0$ and $\lambda\ne0$, then $v=0$.  Proof: $0=\lambda^{-1}\cdot0=\lambda^{-1}\cdot(\lambda\cdot v)=(\lambda^{-1}\cdot\lambda)v=1\cdot v=v$.

Answer (score 1):

I think your proof doesn't work like this because:

1. For a general field, you don't necessarily have that the set $\{ 2 \theta, 3 \theta, 4 \theta, 5 \theta, ..., \theta (2 \theta )^{-1}, \theta (3 \theta)^{-1}, ... \}$ is infinite! Take $\mathbb{F}_2 =  \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$ as an example...The set you use is only infinite, if the characteristic of the field is not finite.
2. There are infinite fields with finite characteristic ([see for example here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58424/example-of-infinite-field-of-characteristic-p-neq-0) or consider the algebraic closure of a finite field).
   Your proof only shows that the characteristic has to be finite, but that's not the same as showing that the field is a finite field.

My attempt for proving the statement would be this. (Please be doubtful, I might be wrong!)

*Don't read further if you want to find a proof yourself.*

---

Let $v \in V \setminus \{ 0 \}$ (this exists since $\mathrm{dim}(V) > 0$).
We consider the map
$$
M: F \to V: \lambda \mapsto \lambda v.
$$

- We show by contradiction that the map $M$ is injective. Let $\lambda, \mu \in F$ with $\lambda \neq \mu$ and $\lambda v = \mu v$, then
  $$
  (\lambda - \mu) v = 0
  $$
  but
  $$
  (\lambda - \mu)^{-1} (\lambda - \mu) v = v \neq 0
  $$
  which is a contradiction to the vector space axioms (a zero vector multiplied with anything has to be the zero vector again). Hence there are no such elements such that $\lambda \neq \mu$ and $\lambda v = \mu v$.
- Since $M$ is injective, we get
  $$
  \vert F \vert \leq \vert V \vert < \infty.
  $$