# monic irreducible polynomials

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I need help with :

Let $\Bbb F_3=\Bbb Z_3$ be the field with 3 elements.Show that there are infinitely many monic irreducible polynomials in $\Bbb F_3[x]$ such that $P(0)=-1$.

Now,I saw this proof [Ring of polynomials over a field has infinitely many primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80389/ring-of-polynomials-over-a-field-has-infinitely-many-primes)  but I am not sure,is there any different for this field and with the condition that $P(0)=-1$?

Comment: I would assume you could look at polynomials of the form $x^i(x-1)^j(x+1)^k -1$ for different $i,j,k$.

Comment: Hint: How would you prove there are infinitely many prime natural numbers $p$ such that $p\equiv 2\pmod {3}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given finitely many prime polynomials $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n\in\mathbb F_3[x]$, consider that $xp_1(x)p_2(x)\cdots p_n(x)-1$.

Comment: Hey, you already wrote this...I shall delete my answer now. +1

Comment: And then continue similar to Euclid's proof?

Comment: @Thomas Andrews