# Is there a ring R for which R[x] contains only finitely many irreducible monic polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I am looking for an example (if any) of a ring $R$ for which $R[x]$ contains only finitely many irreducible monic polynomials.

I know that Euclid proof on infinitely many prime numbers works also for $K[x]$ where $K$ is a field (for example here: [Ring of polynomials over a field has infinitely many primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80389/ring-of-polynomials-over-a-field-has-infinitely-many-primes)) but I don't see why this proof does not work for arbitrary ring $R$.

As someone noted, $R$ must be finite because polynomials $x-r$ are irreducible for every $r \in R.$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The argument there works whenever $R$ is a UFD. A counter-example should require $R$ to be finite.

Comment: But how do you use UFD property?